# Why am I getting a runtime error on my new computer but not my 2 older computers when running the same vba macro?

Tags: html, excel

```html
html.body.innerHTML = response
' Get the values from the specified element on the page.

With Sheets("Instructions")
    .Range("CurrentPrice") = html.getElementsByClassName("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").Item(0).innerText
'    .Range("CurrentPrice") = html.getElementsByClassName("Px(10px)")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText
    .Range("LowPrice") = html.getElementsByClassName("Px(10px)")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(7).innerText
    .Range("HighPrice") = html.getElementsByClassName("Px(10px)")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(9).innerText
    .Range("AvgPrice") = html.getElementsByClassName("Px(10px)")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(3).innerText
    .Range("SI_score") = html.querySelector("[data-test='rec-rating-txt'").innerText 'Recommendation score
    Sheets("Instructions").Range("Date_PriceTargets") = Now()

End With
```

The following Excel VBA macro code works on my laptop, and my old desktop, but part of the code no longer works on my new desktop, which encounters a "Runtime error 424 Object required" when it gets to the Low, High, Average and SI_score lines of code shown below. I've commented out the second line of code referring to the Current price because it doesn't work also, but I found the Current price value shown also at the top of the same webpage, and I can return that value without a problem (call it a workaround for now). The other values I'm trying to retrieve are on the same webpage but located in a separate frame to the side of the main body called Analysts' Price Targets.

Note that my Excel file is stored on OneDrive so that I can share the same file between all 3 computers. All 3 computers have the latest Windows 10 64-bit build and are signed into the same Office 365 subscription account, and use the same version of the latest Firefox browser. Please note that I have tested the same file on all 3 computers, not copies of the file, so Excel and this VBA macro should run the same on all devices. But something now caused or is causing the runtime error to occur only on my new computer and only with the specific lines of code I have identified.

Here's an example webpage that the macro scrapes data values from...
https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/ENB.TO/analysis?p=ENB.TO

...and enters the data into the "Instructions" worksheet of my workbook. In summary, 2 of my older computers have no trouble scraping all 5 data values, plus the Now() value. But my desktop can only scrape the "CurrentPrice" value (and Now() value), which is on the same webpage as the other 4 values.

With Sheets("Instructions")
.Range("CurrentPrice") = html.getElementsByClassName("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").Item(0).innerText
' .Range("CurrentPrice") = html.getElementsByClassName("Px(10px)")(0).getElem entsByTagName("span")(1).innerText
.Range("LowPrice") = html.getElementsByClassName("Px(10px)")(0).getElem entsByTagName("span")(7).innerText
.Range("HighPrice") = html.getElementsByClassName("Px(10px)")(0).getElem entsByTagName("span")(9).innerText
.Range("AvgPrice") = html.getElementsByClassName("Px(10px)")(0).getElem entsByTagName("span")(3).innerText
.Range("SI_score") = html.querySelector("[data-test='rec-rating-txt'").innerText 'Recommendation score
Sheets("Instructions").Range("Date_PriceTargets") = Now()

End With

Any ideas as to why my new computer can no longer run through these specific lines of code?

Comment: Have you tried `.Range("LowPrice") = 1` just to see if the problem is on the right or left side of the equal sign?

Comment: Yes. That works.

Comment: In that case it seems the html is different or parsed differently.

Comment: The response I get from the XMLHTTP request on the problem computer is: response ="<!DOCTYPE html><html id="atomic" class="NoJs ie-11 desktop". The response I get from my older computers that work is: response ="<!DOCTYPE html><html id="atomic" class="NoJs lightweight ie-7 desktop". Does that tell you anything?

Comment: Nope. But it seems it's not the same. So probably you need to figure out if the item you are looking for is in the html on the new computer also, and how to get to it.

Comment: I commented out the ".getElementsByTagName("span")(7).innerText" for the Low Price line of code, leaving just the ".Range("LowPrice") = html.getElementsByClassName("Px(10px)")(0)". When I ran the code, it returned a [object HTMLButtonElement] for the .Range("LowPrice") named value. This is on the computer that's not working properly. When I ran the same test on the other two computers that are working properly, I got a return value of [object]. Does that mean that the computers are possibly not even scraping the same webpage?

Comment: Possibly. As I said you need to look in the html and see if you can find the equivalent

Comment: I ran a test on my Acer-desktop (the computer with the problem) and on my Acer-laptop (the computer that works fine) by printing the HTTP GET responses to separate text files. The desktop text file is 243 pages of html and the laptop is only 114 pages. I ran the 2 files through MS Word's Compare feature to highlight the differences and it produced over a hundred differences. More importantly, I then searched the desktop file, but it did not have any instances of the values I'm trying to scrape. The laptop file did. Why are the computers returning different html results?

Comment: There can be loads of reasons, all originating at the webpage and the webpage developer. Could be screen size, touch screen, windows version. Or sometimes they test different layouts on different viewers.

Comment: Found a fix...sort of. I created a new User account on my Acer-desktop for my wife. I then signed into her Microsoft User account, but signed into my Microsoft Office account in Excel under my user ID. I also tried it under her MS Office user account. In both cases, the macro worked like a charm when signed in to her MS User account. When I signed out of her User account and signed in under my User account, the macro failed. Is there a setting in my MS User account that is causing the macro to run differently, or return or block certain webpage data?

Comment: After extensive online support from several Microsoft Online Support agents, I have reluctantly resolved this issue by creating a new user profile for myself.